# jQuery - Selecting specific button nested within div ul li

Tags: php, jquery

I admit to being lost.  I am trying to select a button that is nested within line items in a ul nested within a div

Here's the php creating the menubar.  It is returned via ajax to a div with an id of "menubar".  That part works fine.  However, none of my click functions do anything.

```
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li class = 'menu'><button class = 'menbtn' id='scores'>Scores</button></li>";
echo "<li class = 'menu'><button class = 'menbtn' id='rules'>Rules</button></li>";
echo "<li class = 'menu'><button class = 'menbtn' id='courses'>Courses</button></li>";
echo "<li class = 'menu'><button class = 'menbtn' id='history'>Comments</button></li>";
echo "<li class = 'menu'><button class = 'menbtn' id='history'>Reservation</button></li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

I am assuming I have to use some sort of nested select since a click function for the button with an id of "scores" -  $('#scores') does nothing.  I have tried various nested selectors and have struck out.

If someone could show me the proper selector for the button with the id of "scores" I'll figure it out from there.

Thank you,

DMD

Comment: Take the output markup and JS and paste at jsfiddle or jsbin. Need more context. Click on #scores should be just fine. I'm guessing syntax error or binding before $ is ready or something.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not putting these events in document.ready function. Try putting them in to it.

**Example :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#scores").click(function(){
       // Your Stuff
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add an event listener to your button.

```
$(document).on('click', '#scores', function (){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: My guess as well but the Q lacks a lot of detail.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have invalid markup in your html the button Comments and reservations with the same id, second

the selector it's actually simple it just

```
$("#scores") //<----
```

But since you don't give too much details about how you're constructing the html it's hard to see what's the real solution only guess. One thing could be that you need to used the event `on` to fired the the event handler after added the html by php

for example

```
$("#score").on("click", function(){ //do something});
```

Comment: thanks very much - the ids are okay.  My snippet was incorrectly edited.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that jquery can read the new elements returned by the ajax in the dom.
To inform jquery to re-read the dom you have to call live.

```
$('#scores').live("click",function(){
     alert("you clicked scores");
});
```

Comment: the function live, it's deprecated, you must change by the function `on`

Comment: both .live and .on work and I thank everyone for their suggestions.  I doubt that I would have found the answer on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `live()` method, with the help of this method you can trigger the new element which is added via ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#scores').live('click',function(){
    //Your code
  })
});
```

Comment: thank you.  .live works fine; however I see that it is deprecated in favor of .on which also works.